# No puedo ver las tablas creadas en la consola de H2

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, h2

Tengo un proyecto en Java usando una base de datos H2, y tengo este test:

```
@Test
@Sql("/sql/script.sql")
public void exampleTest() throws Exception{
  ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
    MvcResult mvcResult = mockMvc.perform(get("/api/example/some-thing")).andDo(print())
            .andExpect(status().isOk()).andReturn();
    SomethingDTOSelect[] responseArray = objectMapper.readValue(mvcResult.getResponse().getContentAsString(), SomethingDTOSelect[].class);
    ArrayList<SomethingDTOSelect> responseList = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(responseArray));
    Assert.assertEquals(1, responseArray.length);
    Assert.assertEquals("Example", responseList.get(0).getValue());
}
```

El test se ejecuta correctamente y es exitoso. Dentro de 'script.sql' se hace una creación de una tabla y una inserción de datos, pero cuando ingreso a la consola de H2 no puedo ver la tabla. ¿Cuál es el problema?

Esta es la propiedad de applicaction.properties en src/test

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:DBTEST;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1
spring.datasource.driverClassName=org.h2.Driver
spring.datasource.username=sa
spring.datasource.password=password
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
```